# Setting layoutdirection with supportsrtl=false

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I have an application on which I do not have the liberty to add supportsRtl = true

With that being set to false I have two questions.

1) Is it possible to set supportsRtl true programatically?
2) This is the code that  doesn't work when supportsRtl = false

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
```

Any ideas as to how can I have a single layout file be displayed in ltr/rtl while the supportsRtl is false?

Comment: Why exactly don't you "have the liberty" to add that tag?

Comment: Its a legacy application . It breaks apart when i set that to true . Because they have made separate layouts for each file. And they aren't using start and end attributes anywhere. Its pretty sad i am stuck in this predicament

Comment: it may be a lot, but you need to fix those layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Setting **only one layout** direction to `RTL` wouldn't be a good idea since users who uses `RTL` direction will need to see the right texts direction for all Activities-layouts.

Just set the `android:supportsRtl="true"` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` then go to:

```
Refactor -> Add RTL Support Where Possible
```

This will satisfy your need by adding `RTL` to where it's possible.

---

About that `start`-`end` attributes in the xml side, all you need to do is:

```
Right-click on the project -> Replace in Path
```

Then replacing your `start`-`end` attributes easily by using this.